# Prerequisite requirments

Tags: research-process, graduate-school, thesis, advisor, physics

I want to start research in the field of Computational Cosmology. It includes the galaxy formation and reionization era. I know it involves extensive computing techniques including parallel and high performance computation but do I need to study General Relativity (detailed course) or I can work without it (or having its basic concepts)?
For the physics part, I have to study Astrophysical Hydrodynamics and galactic compact objects and their X ray sources etc. 
Do I need complex differential geometry of General Relativity for this? 
P.S: I have a physics background and right now in course-work phase at graduate level in Computational Science degree.

Comment: The list of required courses will most likely be available from your university (and vary by university).

Comment: There is no one in my university (even in my country) who is working in this field. People over here are saying that I have to take Differential Geometery courses for it whereas I don`t see such requirements in international institutions.
I am going to start with a foreign supervisor, who is currently unavailable. That is why asking someone who is working in this field.

Comment: You should ask your (future) supervisor nevertheless, because the way other people would teach it and the requirements they expect of their students might be very different, even if they are in the same field. Especially if it is a fairly new, open field right now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's 100% necessary for computational cosmology but I would highly recommend studying General Relativity if you can, especially if the course includes some cosmology as well (fairly common for undergraduate and graduate courses in GR).

Fluency in differential geometry is (I think) an essential skill for a cosmologist, computational or otherwise. Studying GR and cosmology will also greatly help your understanding of the bigger picture, for example, the FLRW background, the Friedmann and continuity equations etc.

Plus GR is a really beautiful theory! I would recommend that any physicist study it if they have the chance.